# How do I install a crx file on Google Chrome Dev?

Tags: windows, linux, mac, google-chrome, chromium

I'm using Google Chrome 21 Dev and I can't install `.crx` files. I download them, but no popup appears asking if I want to install it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=119607) for **both** Google Chrome and Chromium developer channels since version 19. While there is currently no *official* fix for this, there is a hack to get this to work. For this tutorial, I'm going to use the [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/download-chrome.html).

1. First, download the extension.
2. Now, navigate to the directory and unzip `RES.crx`. You should get a bunch of items
    that are related to RES. Put all these items in their own folder, titled `RES`.
3. Now navigate to `chrome://extensions` and select **Developer Mode**.
4. Click **Load unpacked extension...** and navigate to the folder, `RES`.
5. Click the open button to install the extension.

While this is a "dirty hack," it will allow you to install extensions until this bug is fixed.